# Problem with exceeding memory

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm having memory problems to plot a file with 4000 values. I've consulted several questions related to this problem and I've tried the externalization approach. The code is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external} 
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xlabel=tau,
ylabel=y1]
\addplot table [x=tau, y=y1]{data.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

and I've this on the compiler:

```
    pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape %.tex
```

I'm getting two errors:

```
    Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-e
    TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=3000000]. \end{tikzpicture}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: See the pgfplot manual section 6.2 Memory Limitations p 525 https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots

Comment: I decided to use and now it works, thank you!